# Angular.js UI-ROUTER: ui-sref is not adding the hash tag(#) in href parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, ui-sref

I have one problem. I am using `UI-ROUTER` of Angular.js in my app. I am explaining my code below.

```
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="product.eVouchers.dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
```

The above li tag is generating below output

```
<a ui-sref="product.eVouchers.dashboard" href="/product/eVoucher/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

As I have not removed the hash(#) tag yet inside href parameter the `#` should come first like `<a ui-sref="product.eVouchers.dashboard" href="#/product/eVoucher/dashboard">Dashboard</a>` for this reason only when I am trying to open this same page in new tab by right click the page is not coming.

I am explaining my route file below.

```
   var Admin=angular.module('medilink',['ui.router','ngMessages','ngFileUpload','ui.bootstrap','720kb.datepicker']);
    Admin.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
          $rootScope.$state = $state;
        });
    Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/product');
        $stateProvider
         .state('product', { 
                url: '/product',
                templateUrl: 'productview/product.html',
                controller: 'productController'
            })
        .state('product.eVouchers',{
            url:'/eVoucher',
            templateUrl:'VoucherView/mas.html',
            controller: 'eVoucherController'
        })
        .state('product.eVouchers.dashboard',{
            url:'/dashboard',
            templateUrl:'VoucherView/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
       $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: false
    });
    });
```

Here I need the `#` tag as href parameter with other value in generated html output. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to HTML 5 mode. Check the doc:

**[AngularJS Documentation for $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)**

Just turn it off:

```
.config(['$locationProvider',
    function ($locationProvider) {

        // html 5 mode is by default turned off, so be sure 
        // that it is not turned on somewhere
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:false});
}]);
```

Comment: `html5mode` doesn't disabled by default ? link here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#-location-service-configuration

Comment: If the # is missing, HTML 5 mode is in play... right?

Comment: Yes..may be OP has missed to add the `$locationProvider.html5Mode` line its config phase in question(Code)

Comment: Exactly... that is what seems to be a reason... at least to me

Comment: @RadimKöhler : I did as per you still issue is same.I have posted my updated route file.Please check .

Comment: @subhra your settings seem ok. But because it is not working, I guess, (that seems to be the only way) that somewhere ELSE in your code - html 5 is turn off. By default the # will be there with angular and ui-router. No other way. so please, really check your setting

Comment: @RadimKöhler : The `# ` is coming in my URL on address bar i.e-the html5 mode is disabled.Can you please tell me how can i check this?

Comment: Not sure if I do understand it now. So - hash # is now coming? Then solved, right? because without html5 - all should be working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Turn off html5Mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)
```

If it does not work, maybe your AngularJS version is v1.3.x. This is a bug in AngularJS v1.3.x, see [issue report](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1408).

Just update angular.js to latest v1.5.7, and angular-ui-router.js to v0.2.11. It will work.